# Mounting my external hard disk takes to much time(USB 3.0)[LINUX]

Tags: 14.04, usb, mount, hard-drive, mountpoint

I am trying to mount my external hard disk using :

```
sudo mount -t ntfs-3g /dev/sdc2 /mnt/backUp
```

It is taking around 3 minutes to finish mounting. I even got this following error:

```
    Failed to write lock '/dev/sdc2': Resource temporarily unavailable
    Error opening '/dev/sdc2': Resource temporarily unavailable
    Failed to mount '/dev/sdc2': Resource temporarily unavailable
```

I then created a a new mount directory and mounted it which again took 3 minutes. Reading files or unzipping files are also taking too much time. I am not sure what is happening or how to improve my read and transfer speed. Any help given is appreciated here.

Thanks

Comment: Does it eventually mount after 3 minutes? Is this a Windows C: drive, or just a data drive? If you have Windows installed, can you perform a `chkdsk` on this drive? If, instead of issuing a `mount` command, what happens if you open a `Files` (Nautilus) window and click on its name in the left pane?

Comment: This is Linux OS. Yes it does mount eventually after couple of minutes. I tried it with another hard disk with the same hardware specifications(let's call it HD2). HD2 is faster(62 MB/sec) than this current HD(2 MB/sec). I am not sure what is causing one to be faster than the other. Could it be more of a h/w issue than a s/w issue?
Nautilus command loads the files, but again slowly.

Comment: You didn't answer all of my questions. Are these NTFS disks, or something else? In terminal, do `sudo fdisk -l` when the USB HDD is connected, and lets see if there's a partition alignment problem.

Comment: @heynnema
It is NTFS disks
`sudo fdisk -l` :
`Disk /dev/sdc: 5001.0 GB, 5000981077504 bytes
256 heads, 63 sectors/track, 605626 cylinders, total 9767541167 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 33553920 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x1cae299a

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdc1               1  4294967295  2147483647+  ee  GPT
Partition 1 does not start on physical sector boundary.`
**The other output for the second hard disk is in next comment**

Comment: `Disk /dev/sdd: 5001.0 GB, 5000981077504 bytes
256 heads, 63 sectors/track, 605626 cylinders, total 9767541167 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 33553920 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x1cae2998

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdd1               1  4294967295  2147483647+  ee  GPT
Partition 1 does not start on physical sector boundary.
`

Comment: Normally information like the `sudo fdisk -l` output should be put into your question, by using copy/paste and then edit your question to add that output. When placed in the comment section, it's REAL hard to read. But, from what I can see, each disk has only one partition, yes? And that partition is misaligned, which can cause real performance issues. How did your initialize these disks? Did you use a Windows tool, or gparted, or something else?

Comment: Thank you! You're right. It makes more sense to paste output in the question. How did you infer that the partition is misaligned? They were initialized using gparted.

Comment: `sudo fdisk -l` is a quickie way to tell if partitions are misaligned... and when it says "Partition 1 does not start on physical sector boundary", they're misaligned. You can use the `parted` app to do a more correct test. See `man parted` for more info. In `gparted` did you have the `Align partitions to...` enabled? What I can't tell you is the actual performance impact in your environment.

Comment: I am not sure when the alignment option is. I also came across this on searching for that option:  __The Cylinder/Head/Sector values reported by modern disk devices no longer have a direct physical relationship to the data stored on the disk device. Hence it is no longer valid to use this alignment setting to achieve enhanced performance.__

Comment: The `gparted` align option appears when you create a new partition. To do a more correct alignment check... `sudo parted -l` and `sudo parted align-check optimal partition_number`. The old CHS methods haven't been used in years.